# unable to use renderman in 2.77

Tags: rendering, add-on, renderman-render-engine

I was using Renderman in 2.76, but am unable to use it in 2.77. When I try to enable it in the user prefs it can't find the DLL but it's there.

Comment: You are using *PR-Man-for-Blender* Add-on, right? If so, please report this issue on [github](https://github.com/bsavery/PRMan-for-Blender) instead. Also it seems that this is solved already: https://github.com/bsavery/PRMan-for-Blender/issues/216